# Creating a list of Exceptions in java

Tags: java, list, exception, collections

I want to create a list of Exceptions in java. Something like -

```
List<Exception> ex = new ArrayList<Exception>();

ex.add(NotFoundException.class);
```

but on doing so I am getting en error -

```
The method add(Exception) in the type List<Exception> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<NotFoundException>)
```

Eclipse IDE suggest to change to `addAll()` but that didn't solve the issue either.

Can someone please let me know how can we build a `List` or `Collection` of `Exception`s?

Comment: What do you think `.class` is?

Comment: Do you want a list of instance of exception or a list of classes of exceptions ?

Comment: What do you intend to do with this `List`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the difference between an object and its class.

If you want have a list of classes:

```
List<Class<? extends Exception>> list = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Exception>>();
list.add(Exception.class);
```

If you want to have a list of Exceptions:

```
List<Exception> list = new ArrayList<Exception>();
list.add(new Exception("Help! A problem!"));
```

Comment: Note neither example actually works except for `Exception.class`/`new Exception()`, due to your bounds.

Comment: Yeah true, for a functional list of classes the bounds would need to be relaxed. I was sort of operating on the assumption that the original questioner really wanted a list of Exceptions, not a list of classes, so I didn't really think about how confining the bounds would be in the Class list,

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually adding the instances of Exception worked but not the class. So List<Class<Exception>> list = new ArrayList<Class<Exception>>();
list.add(RuntimeException.class); didnt work and showing the same error.

Comment: Don't you mean `List<Class<? extends Exception>>`? Notice the allowance of subclasses, not just `Exception.class` itself.

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly what you'd need to do to have a functional list of Exception classes, I'll update my solution, thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding classes, not exceptions.

```
List<Class<? extends Exception>> ex = new ArrayList<>();

ex.add(Exception.class);
```

Comment: Might want to give some bounds there.

Answer (score -1):

You should Exception instances to the list. Not the class

e.g.

```
List<Exception> ex = new ArrayList<Exception>();
ex.add(new FileNotFoundException());
ex.add(new MyException());
```

Comment: following the question requirement example, he is asking about howto define a list of class types not class instances (objects)

Answer (score -1):

You have created list of exceptions, i.e. list that can hold instances of exceptions. But you try to add there `class` instead.

the following will work

```
List<Exception> ex = new ArrayList<Exception>();
ex.add(new NotFoundException());
```

(obvioously if your `NotFoundException` has default constructor; otherwise use appropriate contructor).

The following will work too:
    List> ex = new ArrayList>();
    ex.add(NotFoundException.class);

now it depends what do you really need.

Comment: following the question requirement example, he is asking about howto define a list of class types not class instances (objects)